# MATLAB newbie: problem reading in file when the file name is stored in a string

Tags: matlab, fopen

I am using Matlab to read in and process calculation results.  I use fopen.

My problem is that I currently have to specify a path to each file each time I need to use it in my processing code.  For example, this works:

```
fid = fopen('/Users/me/Desktop/Result1/velocity.tbl', 'r+');
liqmass = textscan(fid, '%f %*f %*f %*n %f %*n %*n %*n %*n %*n %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f', 'headerlines', 1, 'delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', 1);
fclose(fid);
```

But I want to do this:

```
velocityOut = '/Users/me/Desktop/Result1/velocity.tbl';  % Specify a path once in an easy-to-reach place
fid = fopen(velocityOut, 'r+');
    liqmass = textscan(fid, '%f %*f %*f %*n %f %*n %*n %*n %*n %*n %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f', 'headerlines', 1, 'delimiter', ',', 'CollectOutput', 1);
    fclose(fid);
```

However, I get the following error:
??? Undefined function or variable 'velocityOut'.

I can't figure out why it isn't working.  I would be very grateful if someone could point out my mistake.  Thank you.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps you might not have evaluated `velocityOut` before evaluating the rest of it. Can you try clearing all variables and evaluating all 4 lines?

Comment: Thanks a lot yoda...  If I understand you correctly, you're saying to take the lines out of my m-file and put them in individually at the command window.  I did that and it works!  I don't understand why the same thing won't work when in the m-file.  The definition of velocityOut is definitely before the fopen call.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm an idiot yoda.  You are exactly right.  Figured it out.  Thanks very much!!  I don't see how to mark your answer correct, since it is a comment.  I'd like to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above is correct, and should work fine. Perhaps you might not have evaluated `velocityOut` before trying to use it in `fopen`. So if you are working from the command window, you'll need to evaluate it first, or if it's in a script, it should be defined *prior* to being used in `fopen`.